# MVC Forms Authentication with custom database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get forms authentication working for an mvc site. I have a custom database with a users table, and I would like to do my own password validation.

I am logging in my user like this:

```
if (PasswordHasher.Hash(password) == dataUser.Password)
{
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true);
   return true;
}
```

The problem is, when the session expires obviously the user has to login again.

I am thinking I should be storing this Auth cookie in my users table?

**Update:** I'm obviously in desperate need of more education in this area. I just noticed that the user stays authenticated even after an iisreset.

I guess what I'm asking is how can I get persistent and non persistent authentication working properly. I want a user to not have to login again if they click "remember", and if they don't then their authentication should expire when the forms authentication is set to expire.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  How do you store a cookie in a database table?

Comment: What I was thinking was that I would need some way to associate the forms authentication cookie with something in my database, in the case of an app restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to put my variable in the second argument of the SetAuthCookie method. It was always sending true for the "persistent" argument. FML.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend implementing a custom [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) so you can leverage the existing controls or patterns that are out there for the existing membership providers.